# Google Chrome breaks rowspan from time to time?

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, browser, html-table

We've build a complex and dynamic layout with a few colspans/rowspans in there. The page Looks good in IE and FF, as well as in Chrome. Most of the time in Chrome... When I refresh the page by clicking F5 it can happen, that the layout is suddenly wrong, the rowspan is not rendered correctly. This happens only every 5th time, sometimes every 10th time. What can be the reason?

Example:

```
---------------
|       |  |  |
--------|  |  |
|   |   |  |  |
---------------
```

suddenly becomes something like

```
---------------
|       |  |  |
|       |  |  |
|       |  |  |
|--------------
|   |   |  |  |
---------------
```

but yeah, not every time, not in other Browsers, only in Chrome and only from time to time.

SourceFile: https://files.fm/u/yhvtk6cz#

Comment: Can you make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can also test and fix the problem?

Comment: I'll try so, just give me a few minutes!

Comment: I have uploaded the file to --> https://files.fm/u/yhvtk6cz
Let me know, if there are any problems getting the file from there.
Watch the box (td) on the left top. If you refresh the page (in Chrome) it sometimes grows and sometimes shrinks.

Comment: At the files you posted, I cannot see the problem with google chrome, it looks like it is coming from code on the server, can you compare the source-code of the working version with the not working version?

Comment: did you klick F5 often enough? Sometimes it happens just every 2ßth, 30th, 40th.... time... it' s soo crazy!
Oh, meanwhile I found out that it works ok (or seems to be) when I remove the last three tr's in the Code. But I don't see an error in there...